# Create and write to file > start application > delete file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a VB.NET application which writes multiple lines of text into a text file, then starts an application and after the application started, deletes the text file.

How exactly can I realize that?

--

Edit:

I now got this code:

```
    Dim iniFile As String = Application.StartupPath + "\settings.ini"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(iniFile) = True Then
        File.Delete(iniFile)
    End If

    If System.IO.File.Exists(iniFile) = False Then
        File.Create(iniFile)
    End If

    Dim fileStr As String() = {"line1", "line2", "line3"}
    File.WriteAllLines(iniFile, fileStr)

    Dim p As Process = Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\app.exe")
    p.WaitForInputIdle()

    If System.IO.File.Exists(iniFile) = True Then
        File.Delete(iniFile)
    End If
```

The only problem I got, is that VS is telling me, the file is in use. Between creating and editing the file. Any ideas for that?

Comment: What are you trying to do? first of all, before deleting the file you might check if `File.Exists = True` not `False`... Second, the line `Dim fileStr As String()...` doesn't add the lines to the created file, that only creates a string array

Comment: Are you trying to pass some configuration parameters to the starting application and then deleting the file but only after the application has read them?

Comment: Exactly, @Steve. The Application reads from the .ini file. But I dont want the user to see this file at all.

Comment: And how are you sure that the starting application reads all config at its startup and not after a while when the info is needed? Do you own the source code of this application? If yes then perhaps it is better to pass them as command line arguments

Comment: @Steve. Unfortunately, I can't edit the sourcecode of the application.

Comment: Then you can't delete the file until the started application terminates and this means that also you app should remain active until that point

Comment: The application reads stuff from the file, but isn't using it while it's running.

Comment: Check my managed INI file-settings parser. it's user-friendly to use and you will avoid those stream-is-in-use kind of errors. https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/master/Solution/v1.5/Elektro.Application/Settings/Types/IniManager.vb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is starting the app and then moving straight on to delete the ini file.

You need to wait for the process to exit first before you continue with deleting the ini file

E.g

> ```
> {code to create ini file}
>
> 'Start the process.
> Dim p As Process = Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\app.exe")
> 'Wait for the process window to complete loading.
> p.WaitForInputIdle()
> 'Wait for the process to exit.
> p.WaitForExit()
>
> {code to delete ini file}
> ```

Full example here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305368

Comment: I don't want to delete the process file, but the .ini file, which isn't used after the app started.

Comment: @aequabit this code doesn't delete the process variable. It waits for the process to finish running before it deletes the ini file.

Comment: This code waits for the started application to end, in light of user's comment perhaps is enough to WaitForInputIdle...

Comment: @stormCloud I actually want to delete the .ini file right after the application started.

Comment: @aequabit ok, well then go with Steve's comment of just calling WaitForInputIdle, and don't bother with the WaitForExit. This will make sure that the app has loaded before you delete the ini file.

Comment: Okay, the only problem I got now, is that vb.net is telling me, settings.ini is already in use. Right between creating and writing to the file.

Comment: @aequabit if you're using WriteAllLines then you don't need the file.create function. WriteAllLines should make the file for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `File.WriteAllText`
Note: As others already mentioned, you should check against `True` in your last `If`

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\settings.ini") = False Then
    File.Create(Application.StartupPath + "\settings.ini")
End If

Dim fileStr As String() = {"line1", "line2", "line3"}
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\settings.ini", [String].Join(Environment.NewLine, fileStr))

Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\app.exe")

If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\settings.ini") = True Then
    File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\settings.ini")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.WriteAllLines` since it

> Creates a new file, write the specified string array to the file, and then closes the file. [...] If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.
>   [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/92e05ft3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also you should use `Path.Combine` to setup your [path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim path as String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "settings.ini")
Dim fileStr As String() = {"line1", "line2", "line3"}
File.WriteAllLines(path, fileStr)
```

Use the Path.Combine for the `Process.Start` and `File.Delete` too.